# Is this intergral inequality valid?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Does the inequality $\int_2^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt x(\log x)^3 + (1+ \log x^2) x}{x(\log x)^2(x^2 - 1)} \,\mathrm {d}x > \ln \dfrac{17}{10}$ hold ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica says that

```
NIntegrate[ (Sqrt[x] Log[x]^3 + x (1 + 2 Log[x]))/( 
     x Log[x]^2 (x^2 - 1) ), {x, 2, Infinity}] - Log[17/10] // N
```

is about $1.08424$,
so yes.